# What does this te form mean? あれ？お前ケガ治ってね？

Tags: grammar, て-form, anime

> あれ？お前ケガ治**って**ね？

It is at the end, and I don't really understand why. Why would a person choose to use te form? (btw the person saying this doesn't say anything after, so I don't think its some kind of connective)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very casual, slangy form of 「治ってない（か）？」 (not sentence-end ね). It's a little hard to say without context, but it sounds like the wounds healing was a surprise to the speaker, and the ～ている form is used in this case because the wounds *have* healed, rather than it being a future event.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you have the correct context, but this is not ている form, is it? its just classic te form with ね after it, isnt it? i am missing something, can you explain more about it? i have always seen ていない、ている expressed differently, for example with 何やってるんだ- 何やって**ん**だ, or 治って**ん**か- 治ってないか, でき**ん**か-できないか

Comment: @bulgur69 No, I explicitly said this is *not* sentence end ～ね. ～ない (and sometimes あい in general) can transform to ～ねえ (ええ) in rough slangy speech, and especially in young people's questions further shorten to ～ね. This is not particular to ～ている; somebody might suggest to go home like 「さ、もう帰らね？」

Comment: okay! thanks! so it can be translated like "oh, arent your wounds already healing?" ?

Comment: @bulgur69 This ている is probably perfective rather than progressive, so it's "Haven't your wounds healed?"